# Xbox 360 green light turns on but it does not work or boot up

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

When I turn on my xbox 360 I can hear the fan working and The green light in the middle turns on. I am not able to connect a controller. When I turn on my tv nothing shows up. My xbox had been working perfectly fine a couple of minutes ago. When I tried to turn it on again this happened. The adapter light is orange when the xbox is off and when I turn the Xbox on it turns green. I am able to open and close the disc tray to insert a game disk but nothing happens. Does any one know what the problem is?

Comment: I'd suggest checking the HDMI cable and input on your TV (assuming you use HDMI to connect the 360 to your TV).  Mine won't connect controllers or finish booting without the TV being connected and the input properly set.

Comment: [If it is turning itself off after a while this may be helpful](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/30947/42984)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to get yourself a new xbox or send it to Microsoft if you still have warranty (if you have something like x360key, obivously remove it first). It has nothing to do with the HDMI cable (or any other cable) since you can't connect an controller (you could try another controller).

Comment: I would agree, but if you've already taken it apart to use an x360key you probably have voided the warranty :/ which would suck and the cost to repair is the cost of a 360 anymore. If you've done this option, you're out of luck on a free repair.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Xbox do the spinning ring of light on boot? If it does, do you have other screen cables? Did you change screen settings recently? If you have recently changed resolution to a higher pixel ratio (1080p from 720p or 480p) you might need to connect a pair of cables that switch from HDTV to TV and use the TV option for the moment, this will force the 360 to rewrite the config of the resolution and use 480p for standard CRT TVs. Chances are that if you can't get any picture at all form either your HDMI or Standard screen cables that the video component is shot and you would need to contact xbox support. It's rare but I've seen it happen and falls under warranty if the xbox is still in the three to four year warranty.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of things that can be causing this. Is your connection cable in right? Is the connections on the Xbox on right? Are you on the right TV input? If using three cables, are the colors on the correct positions? Is the HDMI cable broken? Is the ring around the xbox red? Check them out before submitting for a new Xbox.

Answer (score -2):

Change composite cables (red white yellow) or hdmi connecting to tv. That will fix it because your xbox cables are damaged.

Comment: Why will this fix it?  Add in some more information about that, please.

Comment: How do you know their cables are damaged?  Have you encountered this before?  Is there something in what the asker has said that makes you believe that this is the problem?